# How to Add Image in Excel Sheet from Database using iText in Java

Tags: java, excel, swing, noclassdeffounderror

i was faceing some problem in creating Excel Report using iText in Java. I want to retrieve some data containing image file from database and export it into Excel Sheet but image file is not appearing in Excel Sheet. And Getting Error Like :

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/codec/digest/DigestUtils
    at org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook.addPicture(HSSFWorkbook.java:1705)
    at CompInfoTable.ExcelReport(CompInfoTable.java:301)
    at CompInfoTable$6.actionPerformed(CompInfoTable.java:748)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.AWTEventMulticaster.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.commons.codec.digest.DigestUtils
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    ... 40 more
```

I have try many times with different code but is always getting error. This is my code:

```
public void ExcelReport()
    {
        try
        {
        filename="Company Report.xls";
        workbook=new HSSFWorkbook();
        HSSFSheet sheet=workbook.createSheet("Company Report");
        HSSFRow rowhead;
        HSSFCell cellhead;

        /*-------------------------------Adding A Custom Color ------------------------*/
        /* HSSFPalette palette=workbook.getCustomPalette();
           palette.setColorAtIndex(new Byte ((byte)41), new Byte ((byte)82), new Byte ((byte)35), new Byte ((byte)85));
           style.setFillForegroundColor(palette.getColor(41).getIndex());
        /*-------------------------------Adding A Custom Color ------------------------*/

        HSSFCellStyle style=workbook.createCellStyle();
        style.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        style.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);           
        style.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);      
        style.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        style.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        style.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER);
        style.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        style.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.DARK_RED.getIndex());

        HSSFCellStyle style1=workbook.createCellStyle();
        style1.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        style1.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);          
        style1.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);     
        style1.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        style1.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        style1.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER);
        style1.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        style1.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.DARK_TEAL.getIndex());

        HSSFFont font3=workbook.createFont();
        font3.setFontName("Calibri");
        font3.setFontHeightInPoints((short)20);
        font3.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        font3.setItalic(true);
        font3.setColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex());
        style.setFont(font3);

        HSSFFont font1=workbook.createFont();
        font1.setFontName("Calibri");
        font1.setFontHeightInPoints((short)18);
        font1.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        font1.setItalic(true);
        font1.setColor(IndexedColors.WHITE.getIndex());
        style1.setFont(font1);



        HSSFCellStyle style2=workbook.createCellStyle();
        style2.setBorderBottom(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        style2.setBorderLeft(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);          
        style2.setBorderRight(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);     
        style2.setBorderTop(HSSFCellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM);
        style2.setAlignment(CellStyle.ALIGN_CENTER);
        style2.setVerticalAlignment(CellStyle.VERTICAL_CENTER);
        style2.setFillPattern(CellStyle.SOLID_FOREGROUND);
        style2.setFillForegroundColor(IndexedColors.SEA_GREEN.getIndex());

        HSSFFont font2=workbook.createFont();
        font2.setFontName("Calibri");
        font2.setFontHeightInPoints((short)14);
        font2.setBoldweight(HSSFFont.BOLDWEIGHT_BOLD);
        font2.setItalic(true);
        font2.setColor(IndexedColors.BLACK.getIndex());
        style2.setFont(font2);

        rowhead=sheet.createRow(4);
        cellhead=rowhead.createCell(0);
        cellhead.getRow().setHeightInPoints(30);
        CellRangeAddress cellrange=new CellRangeAddress(4,5,0,7);
        sheet.addMergedRegion(cellrange);

        HSSFRegionUtil.setBorderBottom(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM,cellrange,sheet, workbook);
        HSSFRegionUtil.setBorderLeft(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM,cellrange,sheet, workbook);
        HSSFRegionUtil.setBorderRight(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM,cellrange,sheet, workbook);
        HSSFRegionUtil.setBorderTop(CellStyle.BORDER_MEDIUM,cellrange,sheet, workbook);

        cellhead.setCellValue("Company Information");
        cellhead.setCellStyle(style);

        rowhead=sheet.createRow(8);
        cellhead=rowhead.createCell(0);
        cellhead.getRow().setHeightInPoints(25);
        cellhead.setCellValue("Comp_Name");
        cellhead.setCellStyle(style1);

        cellhead=rowhead.createCell(1);
        cellhead.setCellValue("Comp_Address");
        cellhead.setCellStyle(style1);

        cellhead=rowhead.createCell(2);
        cellhead.setCellValue("Comp_Contact");
        cellhead.setCellStyle(style1);

        cellhead=rowhead.createCell(3);
        cellhead.setCellValue("Comp_Email");
        cellhead.setCellStyle(style1);

        cellhead=rowhead.createCell(4);
        cellhead.setCellValue("Comp_TIN");
        cellhead.setCellStyle(style1);

        cellhead=rowhead.createCell(5);
        cellhead.setCellValue("Comp_ST");
        cellhead.setCellStyle(style1);

        cellhead=rowhead.createCell(6);
        cellhead.setCellValue("Comp_CIN");
        cellhead.setCellStyle(style1);

        cellhead=rowhead.createCell(7);
        cellhead.setCellValue("Comp_Image");
        cellhead.setCellStyle(style1);

        for(int i=0;i<=7;i++)
        {
            sheet.setColumnWidth(i,7000);
        }

        query="Select * from CompanyInfo";
        PStat=con.prepareStatement(query);
        res=PStat.executeQuery();

        int Row=10;

        while(res.next())
        {
            rowhead=sheet.createRow(Row);
            cellhead=rowhead.createCell(0);
            cellhead.setCellValue(res.getString("Comp_Name"));
            cellhead.setCellStyle(style2);
            cellhead=rowhead.createCell(1);
            cellhead.setCellValue(res.getString("Comp_Address"));
            cellhead.setCellStyle(style2);
            cellhead=rowhead.createCell(2);
            cellhead.setCellValue(res.getString("Comp_Contact"));
            cellhead.setCellStyle(style2);
            cellhead=rowhead.createCell(3);
            cellhead.setCellValue(res.getString("Comp_Email"));
            cellhead.setCellStyle(style2);
            cellhead=rowhead.createCell(4);
            cellhead.setCellValue(res.getString("Comp_TIN"));
            cellhead.setCellStyle(style2);
            cellhead=rowhead.createCell(5);
            cellhead.setCellValue(res.getString("Comp_ST"));
            cellhead.setCellStyle(style2);
            cellhead=rowhead.createCell(6);
            cellhead.setCellValue(res.getString("Comp_CIN"));
            cellhead.setCellStyle(style2);

            //InputStream is=new FileInputStream((res.getBytes("Comp_Images")).toString());
            //byte[] bytes=IOUtils.toByteArray(is);
            byte[] bytes=res.getBytes("Comp_Images");
            int pics=workbook.addPicture(bytes,HSSFWorkbook.PICTURE_TYPE_JPEG);
            //is.close();
            CreationHelper helper=workbook.getCreationHelper();
            Drawing drawing=sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
            ClientAnchor anchor=helper.createClientAnchor();
            anchor.setCol1(7);
            anchor.setRow1(Row);
            Picture picture=drawing.createPicture(anchor, pics);
            picture.resize();
            Row++;
        }
FileOutputStream fileout=new FileOutputStream(filename);
                            workbook.write(fileout);
                            fileout.close();
                            workbook.close();
                            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Excel file is Generated");
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,e);
    }
    }
```

Comment: Based on your error, you need to include the [Apache Commons Codec library](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) within you applications class path - Check the documentation for iText for find out more about it's required dependencies

Comment: See also [tag:noclassdeffounderror]. This is a common problem and you should search previous questions and solutions before asking.